# Multiple claims in one questions

Tags: discussion

Recent example:

[Thermal advantage of "server" CPUs over "consumer" CPUs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/advantages-of-server-cpus-over-consumer-cpus)

What should we do with a question which contains multiple claims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the user to limit it to one question. If they don't oblige, close as "not a real question."